# UPDATE SQL based on 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table structure

Locations

```
LocationName|Easting|Northing
```

Incidents

```
LocationString|Easting|Northing|LocationName
```

LocationString is a badly formatted Subway Station Name that the user of the application can type any old rubbish in to. The eastings and Northings (Co-ordinates) are consistent however. Using them i can give the location a consistent name by looking those values up in a look up table.

In ACCESS SQL i would  do the following

```
UPDATE INCIDENTS, Locations
SET Incidents.LocationName = Locations.LocationsName
WHERE Incidents.Easting = Locations.Easting
AND
Incidents.Northing = Locations.Northing
```

How do i accomplish the same in T-SQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE I
SET I.LocationName = L.LocationsName
FROM Incidents I
JOIN Locations L
ON I.Easting = L.Easting AND I.Northing = L.Northing
```

Comment: +1 I'm resisting my OCD urge to change your table aliases to `I` and `L` so they're a bit more meaningful. :-)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: Ok, ok, i'm changing it myself to help your OCD (and, well, so they're a bit more meaningful)